# How to update nodes within a P2P network?

Tags: p2p, updates, auto-update

Supposed I have a P2P network with *lots* of nodes. If I want to update the P2P client there is one thing I do *not* want to do: Update each single node.

Now I could imagine updating *one* node, and from time to time, each node checks whether the node it currently interacts with is a newer version - and if so, gets the update from that node.

This way, updates would find their way through the P2P network and all you had to do was update one node. Moreover, you'd not be dependent from a central server.

Is there (somewhere out there ;-)) a concept for such an update scenario?

What might be the pros / cons of this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Pros: If for any other reason, it would be really cool to discuss and talk about.

Cons:

- Could be a security hole. If I can put a rogue peer on the P2P
  network, my code could advertise an update that is actually a virus. You
  should at least make sure updates including some sort of code signing
  and authentication piece.
- If there's any sort of bug in the P2P protocol or in the update code,
  then you could get into a state where you are only able to upgrade a subset of all
  nodes.

A better approach might be to just let the clients get their updates from a centralized location.  A hybrid approach would be to notify peers of an update via a central server that advertises a URL and a file hash. If the nodes can get the update from a peer (and validate the hash and code signing), then great. But always have "download from central server" as a fallback.

You might also want to consider how to incorporate a "staged rollout" so that only a limited number of peers receive an update. So you can validate the update works ok on a small set before pushing it out to all the other peers.

Comment: Well, I don't see the issue with the security hole: You need to verify a so-called "update package" using a certificate (or whatever) the same way as with a central server. What I dislike about the central server approach is the dependency ... but of course you are right that it would be great to have something such as a staged rollout.

Comment: @GoloRoden - you didn't mention too many details about your protocol, network, or services. So I can only give you general answers based on experience and from observing others. What I'm basically saying is that once you eliminate having a centralized server for peers to configure their behavior (including updates) from, you lose control of your network. I'd highly recommend you read up on the Skype outage from 2010 as well as the one from 2007. Read this: http://blogs.skype.com/en/2010/12/cio_update.html

Comment: Please be assured that I didn't got you wrong :-). Thanks for your help :-)!